# After clicking on TextInputLayout, the app crashes in Oppo F1S running 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, oppo

I am not able to figure out the cause, I am finding its very difficult to counter the issue.

Its working fine in other devices and even in oppoF7 which is running 8.1.0

This is my XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/til_email"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
  android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
  app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView53">

 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/black" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is styles.xml

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light”> 
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item> 
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item> 
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greish</item> 
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
</style> 

 <style name="ErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat”> 
<item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item> 
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
</style> 

<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat”> 

<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance”> 
<item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item> 
<item name="android:textSize">12sp</item> 
</style>
```

`Stacktrace1`

Getting `android.view.InflateException` on run

```
 Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class TextView
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1595)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:134)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController$SelectionModifierCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:512)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:81)
           at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoSelectionController(OppoEditor.java:417)
           at android.widget.OppoEditor.onTouchEventWrap(OppoEditor.java:322)
           at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8509)
           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8593)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1818)
           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2860)
           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2483)
           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8799)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4866)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4681)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4335)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6694)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6668)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6621)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6853)
           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:216)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

`Stacktrace2`

```
    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:732)
           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:669)
           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1595)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:134)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController$SelectionModifierCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:512)
           at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:81)
           at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoSelectionController(OppoEditor.java:417)
           at android.widget.OppoEditor.onTouchEventWrap(OppoEditor.java:322)
           at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8509)
           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8593)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2110)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1818)
           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2860)
           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2483)
           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8799)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4866)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4681)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4335)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6694)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6668)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6621)
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6853)
           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:216)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:153)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

Comment: This is happening only on oppo device. Can i create emulator with oppo 5.1?

Comment: Have you got solution for that, I am also facing same issue in oppo 5.1.1

Comment: **No till now.**

Comment: Facing a similar problem with "AppCompactTextView" on Oppo devices running on Android 5.0

Did you manage to find any solution?